# Creating navigatable bookmark list in Word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, bookmarks, documents, navigation

How can I create such navigable bookmarks in Microsoft Word (I didnt prepared this doc; I just got this .doc and wondered how we can create those)?
[image]

**Edit**

Ohkay I realize that this can be done by applying one of the Heading styles to the word as explained  [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/word-help/add-a-heading-HA010368882.aspx). Weirdly we need to create styled headings.

**And I now doubt how much customization (in terms of navigation hierarchy not the styling) can be done to these heading-generated navigation tree. Any comment?!!**

One more good thing I realized is that when we save word file having headings as PDF, we can specify in options in Save As window to convert headings to bookmarks in PDF.

Comment: Can you clarify what you are asking?

Comment: @Adam when we apply one of the heading styles in MS Word's Home tab|Style section to any text; it gets populated in Navigation panes' (which can be enabled by View tab|Show section|Navigation Pane) Heading browser; In Save As window -> Save As Type: PDF -> Options button -> Create bookmarks using Headings; it will convert headings hierarchy to PDF's bookmarks hierarchy. Now I doubt what if I want any random text in my doc to appear in Navigation pane? I have to apply it heading style?

Comment: @Adam Or How can I create such style which when I apply to the text it will get added to the headings list?

Comment: Any paragraph that has the Outline Level set to Level 1 or above either directly on the paragraph or through the style should appear in the navigation panel.